# Can i use thematic theme framework for premium theme development?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is it a good decision to use thematic wordpress theme framework to develop premium themes??
is that accepted on most wordpress theme marketplaces?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is a good option and it is accepted at wordpress theme marketplaces